# Receiver for didBecomeActiveNotification never gets called on macCatalyst

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have an SwiftUI App which I made for iPhone/iPads.

Now I'm trying to transfer it to macOS.
One problem I am struggling with is this code block:

```
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
        print("Never called on macOS. Works fine on iPhones.")
        // Do some more stuff.
    }
```

Apple documentations says its available on Mac Catalyst 13.0+, but this code never gets called on macOS.

So my question is:

Where do you put macCatalyst code that should be executed once the program starts (TouchID authentication, e.g.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do you put macCatalyst code that should be executed once the program starts (TouchID authentication, e.g.)?

In `SceneDelegate`

```
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print(#function);
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }
```

it is called once application started in macCatalyst.